# 2 Bugs: Possible Cross-Browser Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a JavaScript game and experiencing 2 problems that I'll try to describe in sufficient detail. (The web page on which the problems is occurring is jaminweb.com/Snake.html).

The first is that one of my even listeners does not seem to be working.

I have, in between `script` tags in my `head`,

```
$("#buttonname").click(function()
{
  alert("good ... the function was called.");
  s = new game(param1, param2, param3);
});
```

and

```
<button id="buttonname">Start Game</button>
```

in my `body`, yet the anonymous function is not getting called. It's not passing the good 'ole alert test that you see I've set up. There are no errors being logged to the console when I load the page.

The second problem is that, while my game works on my computer here at work on Google Chrome, it doesn't work on Firefox and it doesn't work on any browsers when I use my machine at home. The game is not properly detecting when the snake comes in contact with its food. I think the problem lies in these lines:

```
var height = Math.floor($("#somediv").height())+1; 
var width =  Math.floor($("#somediv").width())+1;
```

For some reason, I think those variables are getting calculated differently on some browsers. Could that be the problem, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: have you included the jquery library? is the script enclosed in `$(document).ready()` to ensure that `#buttonname` has been loaded into the html.

Comment: Also, please provide the console's error if any.

Comment: Listen to @Adjit and also try `var height = (Math.floor(parseInt($("#somediv").height()))+1);` or else the JS might be trying to concatenate a string rather than adding integers.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this helps or not, but if you have the button with a hyperlink going somewhere, the address wont work because a URL uses your computer/user name in it and the file name it's saved in so say you did this...

```
<button id="buttonname"> Start </button>
```

and then

```
    $("#buttonname").click(function()
{
  <!-- going to another page here the computer will not be able to find that page because of the user in the link: file:///C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/xxx%20stuff/Corn%20Puff%20Cereal.html
  s = new game(param1, param2, param3);
});
```

another thing is "s" a variable and had you declared that earlier?